# Caching Images React-Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, caching

I have some questions regarding image caching; I am a newbie and am having several difficulties in understanding how and what exactly caching means.

First of all I would like to explain why I want to cach images (in this case just the profile picture):

My user model in MongoDB contains a profilePicture object.

```
"profilePicture": {
    "base64": "",
    "assetType": ""
  }
```

In my react-native application to show the corresponding user image saved in the database I use:

```
<Image source={{ uri: `data:${assetType};base64,${base64}` }} style={styles.userImage} />
```

At the time of Login I save from the server response in the localstorage the data
`storage.set('Base64')` and `storage.set('assetType')`.
To then display them in the component that renders the profilePicture

```
const Pfp = () => {
  const PFPBase64 = storage.getString('PFPBase64');
  const PFPType = storage.getString('PFPType');

  return (
    PFPBase64 && PFPType ? (
      <Image source={{ uri: `data:${PFPPType};base64,${PFPBase64}` }} style={styles.userImage} />
      ) : (
      <ProfilePicture/>
    )
  );
}
```

I'm not actually experiencing major problems, the image seems to load instantly but from what I understand it's not good to save images in the localstorage. So I was wondering if anyone could give me an answer, what approach should I use.